# REGEX - из строки "50см 8м, 0.8шт 12п.м. ..." получить эти значения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка **'50шт, 80дм 0.8м раз One 10см*20см (10см) Машина car 10м 12п.м. hello,hell 40 см. х 70 см.'**

Из неё нужно получить **['50шт', '80дм', '0.8м', '10см', '20см', '10см', '10м', '12п.м.', '40 см.', '70 см.']**

Как с помощью рег. выражений выполнить такую задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const str = '50шт, 80дм 0.8м раз One 10см*20см (10см) Машина car 10м 12п.м. hello,hell 40 см. х 70 см.';
const regExp = /\d*\.?\d+ ?[а-яё.]+/g;

console.log(str.match(regExp));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Evgeniy, да не за что. Галочку тыкните около ответа, если вопрос решен.